# How to permit params to a specific devise_controller with devise_token_auth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I'm using `devise_token_authentication` gem to build token based authentication rails api, then after that I added some extra fields to `Vendor` model through different migration, and in order to permit them I wrote this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :tax_number])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :tax_number])
  end
end
```

Then after that I added another model `Customer` `rails g devise_token_auth:install Customer auth`

then in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Vendor', at: 'vendor/auth'
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Customer', at: 'customer/auth'
end
```

each time I try to `sign_up` with customers through `'localhost:3000/customer/auth'` I got error message: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'tax_number' for Customer.`

So is there any way to permit the extra fields only for `Vendor` model and skip 'Customer' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on [this setup for multiple devise user models.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)

or

If you override the `RegistrationsController` you need to permit extra params directly in `registrationsController`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
  def create

  end

  def account_update

  end

  private


  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :tax_number)
  end
end
```

Comment: I know that, but I need a way without overriding the controllers !